# How to do Prana Pratishtana of Shiv Lingam?

Tags: shiva, shiva-purana, shiva-lingam, linga-purana, pranapratishtha

Recently I got a Shiva Lingam for my home altar. Since its not a Swaymbhu or Banalinga, It must first be energized through Prana Pratishtana. But I do not know the method and mantras for doing the same.

I would like to know How I can do Prana Pratisthana before worshipping Shiva Lingam.

Comment: [Please check](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prana_Pratishtha)

Comment: Thanks. But this article is too brief. I want to know about the particular mantras or hymns and the way in which to consecrate the Shiva Lingam.

Comment: will provide some notes later this week. A lot of information is available in the Puranas. But I see this question is more than a year old. So will add some information for others who may be interested.